# Removing text with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I need some help with javascript and regex.I want to remove some text in title.

I am new to regex and I tried this but it doesn't seems to work.

```
title.replace('/\d{4}\YEAR\d{1,2}\MONTH\d{1,2}\DATE/g', '');
```

Here is what I am trying to remove

> 2012YEAR2MONTH18DATE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
title.replace(/\d{4}YEAR\d{1,2}MONTH\d{1,2}DATE/g, '');
```

Dont put the single quotes for the Regex

Comment: Why `\Y`, `\M` and `\D`? Isn't `title.replace(/\d{4}YEAR\d{1,2}MONTH\d{1,2}DATE/g, '');` enough?